# ReLU weight initialization?

Tags: machine-learning

I have read that the " He weight Initialization"  (He et al., 2015) built on the Lecun weight initialization and suggested  a zero-mean Gaussian distribution where the standard deviation is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0cFk.gif)

and this function should be used with ReLU to solve the vanishing/exploding gradient problem. For me, it does make sense because the way ReLu was built makes it no bothered with vanishing/exploding gradient problem. Since, if the input is less than 0 the derivative would be zero otherwise the derivative would be one. So, whatever the variance is, the gradient would be zero or one. Therefore, the He weight Initialization is useless. I know that I am missing something, that's why I am asking if anyone would tell me the usefulness of that weight initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weight initialization is applied, **in general terms**, to weights of layers that have learnable / trainable parameters, just like `dense layers`, `convolutional layers`, and other layers. `ReLU` is an activation function, fully deterministic, and has no initialization.

Regarding to the vanishing gradient problem, the backpropagation step is funded by computing the gradients by the chain rule (partial derivatives) for each weight (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem)):

> (...) each of the neural network's weights receive an update
>   proportional to the partial derivative of the error function with
>   respect to the current weight in each iteration of training.

The more deep a network is, the smaller these gradients get, and when a network becomes deep enough, the backprop step is less effective (in the worst case, it stops learning) and this becomes a problem:

> This has the effect of multiplying n of these small numbers to compute
>   gradients of the "front" layers in an n-layer network, meaning that
>   the gradient (error signal) decreases exponentially with n while the
>   front layers train very slowly.

Choosing a proper activation function, like `ReLU`, help avoiding this to happen, as you mentioned in the OP, by making partial derivatives of this activation not too small:

> Rectifiers such as `ReLU` suffer less from the vanishing gradient
>   problem, because they only saturate in one direction.

Hope this helps!